# XCode 13 SortOrder is ambiguous

Tags: swift, react-native, couchbase-lite, ios15, xcode13

Check out this error in the most recently updated Xcode (13):

[image]

Did Apple screw something up? How do I fix this? I can see when I start typing SortOrder it shows a Protocol and an Enum.

Comment: I only get the enum. Can you command + click on the protocol version and show where it is defined?

Comment: @George - cannot click on it in the list, when I click on it when there is no list it understandably shows a ? because, heh, it's ambiguous. This is in a react-native app, FWIW. Weird thing is this built fine is XCode 12.

Comment: Worth adding the `react-native` tag as it could be relevant. I only can see `SortOrder` from Foundation

Comment: @George - you are right, there is another dependency that I failed to mention - CouchbaseLiteSwift that is exporting the protocol. Still unsure why this built in Xcode 12. Now, because I'm new to swift stuff, maybe I can ask for help - any idea how to namespace this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the conflicting `SortOrder` enum and protocol, it's ambiguous to the compiler which one you want to use.

Because the `SortOrder` enum is part of the `Foundation` framework, you can do the following to explicitly use it:

```
Foundation.SortOrder
```

Example usage:

```
Foundation.SortOrder.forward
```

Or in your case, you needed `SortOrder` from `CouchbaseLiteSwift`:

```
CouchbaseLiteSwift.SortOrder
```

Comment: In my specific case I actually needed to do `var sort: CouchbaseLiteSwift.SortOrder` but the intention of your answer is correct. Gotta say, `SortOrder` is a pretty generic sounding thing, I can only imagine how many issues exposing this enum from Foundation in iOS 15 this could've potentially caused.

Comment: @Adam It looks like `SortOrder` is new to Foundation as of iOS 15, so I assume that's why there is now a conflict. Glad it helped! (sorry for using wrong `SortOrder`, it's even ambiguous to me :p)